# How to get the exact type of a parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, casting

I have two similar `data class` objects `Post` and `Review`, which both extend my `BasicListItem` class. They also share a view, where their data is being processed and transformed to readable text and images. The idea is fine, but the execution is where I'm struggling with. Let's pick the method for setting up the item view for example:

```
fun setupListItemViews(item: BasicListItem) { //here I pass either the Post or Review item I've received from my backend

//option #1
    var post: Post? = null
    var review: Review? = null
    if (isPost(item)) {
        post = item as Post
    } else {
        review = item as Review
    }
    val data = post ?: review as Review
//this makes "data" a BasicListItem object and I can't access "title" and "description"
//parameters of both Post and Review classes

    item_title.text = data.title //Unresolved reference: title
    item_descr.text = data.description //Unresolved reference: description 
    ...

//option #2
//this way I can handle only the cases where my item is of type Post
//which crashes when I pass an item of type Review, since it's impossible
//to cast Post to Review

   item_title.text = (item as Post).title
   item_descr.text = (item as Post).description
   ...
```

So what exactly should be the way of differentiating the type of `item` if I want to access its parameters?

***Edit***:
This method is not the only place where I need to know the exact type of the method parameter. There are 4 more methods and duplicating code is not an option. I am looking for a clean solution, if such is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the title of your question, [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html) goes into detail about how to cast between types in Kotlin. To demonstrate, I'll clean up your options.

#### Example data structure

Here is the data structure I am using in these examples

```kotlin
open class BasicListItem

data class Post(
  val title: String,
  val description: String,
  val comments: List<String>,
) : BasicListItem()

data class Review(
  val title: String,
  val description: String,
  val score: Int,
) : BasicListItem()
```

As @mightyWOZ [explains in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69106599/4161471), using inheritance would help a lot. But it might not always be possible though - maybe it's external code that you can't change, or refactoring would be too much work.

#### Option 2 - cleaned up

I don't think option 2 is viable, so let's look at it first to get it out of the way.

Kotlin has [safe casting](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator) with the `as?` keyword. If the cast isn't possible, it returns null, and then we can use the [Elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) to handle the nullable object.

```kotlin
fun setupListItemViews(item: BasicListItem) {

  //option #2
  val post: Post? = (item as? Post) // safe cast, returns null if item is NOT an instance of Post 
  val title = post?.title
  val description = post?.description

  println("$title - $description")

}

fun main() {
  setupListItemViews(Post("title", "description", listOf("comment")))
  // output: title - description
  setupListItemViews(Review("title", "description", 10))
  // output: null - null
}
```

In your case I don't think this is a suitable solution, it's too inflexible. Using smart casting and separating out logic into methods is better, which is what Option 1 can do.

#### Option 1 - cleaned up

Here's a cleaned up version of option 1, using [smart casts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#smart-casts) in a `when` statement.

```kotlin
// here I pass either the Post or Review item I've received from my backend
fun setupListItemViews(item: BasicListItem) {

  //option #1
  when (item) {
    is Post   -> handlePost(item) // smart cast item to Post
    is Review -> handleReview(item) // smart cast item to Review
    else      ->
      throw IllegalStateException("unknown item ${item::class} - can't map to ListItemViewDto")
  }
}

// separate the handling of posts and reviews into separate methods

private fun handlePost(post: Post) {
  println("Handling Post: ${post.title} - ${post.description} - ${post.comments}")
}

private fun handleReview(review: Review) {
  println("Handling Review: ${review.title} - ${review.description} - ${review.score}")
}
```

> Note: the `else -> throw` can be eliminated by using [sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html#sealed-classes-and-when-expression)

I think this is the quickest and cleanest option for you - though usually it's best to keep the frontend and backend completely separate (read ['multitier architecture'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) for more details).

At the moment both frontend and backend have a hard dependency on the `Post` and `Review` DTOs. What happens if you want to change a database field? Well, that means updating *all* usages of `Post` or `Review.

Let's make a single class where we can specifically handover from the backend to the frontend.

#### Option 1 - mapper classes

First we need a frontend specific DTO:

```kotlin
/** A DTO to hold data specific to the ListItemView */
data class ListItemViewDto(
  val item_title: String,
  val item_descr: String,
)
```

Next we make a mapper. This should be the only point in which the backend and frontend meet. We're using smart casting again to handle any type of `BasicListItem`, and separate methods to create instances of `ListItemViewDto`.

```kotlin
class ListItemViewMapper {

  /** Map from [BasicListItem] to DTO specifically for [ListItemView] */
  fun fromBasicItem(basicListItem: BasicListItem) = when (basicListItem) {
    is Post   -> mapPost(basicListItem)
    is Review -> mapReview(basicListItem)
    else      ->
      throw IllegalStateException("unknown item ${basicListItem::class} - can't map to ListItemViewDto")
  }

  private fun mapPost(post: Post): ListItemViewDto {
    return ListItemViewDto(
      post.title,
      post.description
    )
  }

  private fun mapReview(review: Review): ListItemViewDto {
    return ListItemViewDto(
      review.title,
      review.description
    )
  }
}
```

Now before the frontend view is created, we can just use the mapper to covert from the database DTO to the frontend DTO.

```kotlin
class ListItemSetup {

  private val mapper: ListItemViewMapper = ListItemViewMapper()

  fun setupListItemViews(basicListItem: BasicListItem) {

    val listItemViewDto: ListItemViewDto = mapper.fromBasicItem(basicListItem)

    println("listItemViewDto: ${listItemViewDto.item_title} / ${listItemViewDto.item_descr}")

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to explain in such detail and for the resources you've provided. I've decided to follow your advice and go with your version of option 1. Regarding the DTOs, I think the separation I have of front-end and back-end is pretty decent (using delegates for every adapter and viewmodel), but I'll definitely take it into consideration during the upcoming refactoring that I'm planning to do. Thanks again for your input, it's valuable and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If both of your `data` classes have some common properties then I suggest you move those properties to a common base class. you can define the base class as

```
abstract class TitleListItem: Base(){
    // Define properties to be abstract, so that they can be overriden
    abstract val title: String
    abstract val description: String
}
```

And now make `Post` and `Review` extend `TitleListItem`. as

```
data class Post(override val title: String,
                override val description: String): TitleListItem()

data class Review(override val title: String,
                  override val description: String): TitleListItem()
```

after this you can update `setupListItemViews` to except a `TitleListItem`.

If you can't change the parameter type of your function then you can do

```
fun setupListItemViews(item: BasicListItem) { 
    // if item is TitleListItem then set text and description
    (item as? TitleListItem)?.let { 
          item_title.text = it.title
          item_descr.text = it.description
     }
}
```

Comment: That seems like a good solution! Unfortunately, it requires a lot of refactoring and since my time is limited I don't think I can go with that solution right now. Thank you for the contribution though, I will take it into consideration when I'm refactoring the code base next month!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply let compiler smartcast your instances to the appropriate type. This allows you to access child class properties within the code block

```
if (item is Post) {
    item_title.text = item.title
    item_descr.text = item.description
} else if (item is Review) {
    item_title.text = item.title
    item_descr.text = item.description
} else {
    // probably you should throw exception here
}
```

assuming your child classes are similar to

```kotlin
class Post(
   var title: String? = null, 
   var description: String? = null, 
   /* other properties */) : BasicListItem()

class Review(
   var title: String? = null, 
   var description: String? = null, 
   /* other properties */) : BasicListItem()
```

Comment: duplication is a smell

Comment: Of course, that's my third obvious option, but this is not the only method where I need to handle this kind problem. I have 4 more methods with a total of 400 lines of code. I really don't want to duplicate them in order to complete the task :/

Comment: @mightyWOZ yes, but monstrous constructions with interfaces and overriden properties are smell as well and are just an overkill for such simple cases (like in OP snippet)

Comment: @G.Rann sorry but you didn't mention that in your question

Comment: You are correct. I forgot to mention that initially. I have edited the post to make it more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing, since my time is short, was to create a method for each type, which called the main `setupListItemViews` with all needed parameters. It looks like this:

```
fun setupListItemViewPost(post: Post) { //the Review method looks the same, but with passed Review object as parameter
    setupListItemView(
        title = post.title,
        descr = post.descr
        comments = post.comments
    )
}

fun setupListItemView(
    title: String,
    descr: String,
    comments: List<Comments>?
    ) {
    println("Title: $title, Description: $descr, Comments: $comments.toString()")
}
```

I know it's not the best way to handle the problem, but it's the best I can think of right now.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a complete code sample please? Ideally with actual data that runs a `@Test` with assertions. At the moment it's missing keywords like `fun` so it's hard to read and figure out why it solves your problem.

Comment: That is correct. I forgot to add the fun keyword in my answer. I've edited it and added some example code to make it more complete.